# JMeter login load test sequence doesn't wait for a request to return?

Tags: session, response, wait, jmeter

I'm running a recorded load test in JMeter. It appears that when the test is replayed, JMeter doesn't wait for the request to respond before proceeding onto the next request in sequence.

How do I address this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that's what's happening? For me it waits for response before dispatching next request. Maybe you're seeing overlapping access? Like, the first user starts to request the next page before the second user receives the first page. Run with only one user to confirm that that's what's really happening.

If what you say really is happening then check the timeout. I always set mine to a longish period - something like 20 seconds.

Also, if your page use cookies, remember that you should not use "Redirect Automatically", instead use "Follow Redirects". "Redirect Automatically" discards the directed page which breaks cookies.